# Including data tables in a page template

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a jsp page where I have a data table. I use the following scripts in the page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I also ad a script for the datatables:

```
<script src="assets/scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

This does not work. When I set the table as a datatable nothing happens. If I replace the jquery scripts with this:

```
<script src="assets/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

The data table works but some other java script menu functionalities in the page stop working (Im using a template). I need to keep the menu functionality and to include a data table in the page. Is this a problem with versions conflicting? If so, then how do I solve it? Thanks.

EDIT: SHOW DATATABLE CODE:

Here is the jquery for the data table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#theTable').DataTable({"sPaginationType": "full_numbers", "bPaginate": true, "bSortClasses": false});
});
```

Comment: show ur datatable code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE2 : 
Use `jQuery.noConflict`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>  

 var $jq164 = jQuery.noConflict(true);  

</script>  

<script src="assets/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

And use for other java script menu functionalities `$jq164('.selector_menu') ...`